# pandas column shift with day 0 value as 0

Tags: python

I've got a pandas dataframe(pivoted) like customer_name, current_date, current_day_count

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| customer | current_date | current_day_count |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Mark     | 2018_02_06   |                15 |
|          | 2018_02_09   |                42 |
|          | 2018_02_12   |                33 |
|          | 2018_02_21   |                82 |
|          | 2018_02_27   |                72 |
| Bob      | 2018_02_02   |                76 |
|          | 2018_02_23   |                11 |
|          | 2018_03_04   |                59 |
|          | 2018_03_13   |                68 |
| Shawn    | 2018_02_11   |                71 |
|          | 2018_02_15   |                39 |
|          | 2018_02_18   |                65 |
|          | 2018_02_24   |                38 |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Now, I want another new column with `previous_day_counts` for each customer but the first day of the customer's previous day value should be 0 something like this `customer`, `current_date`, `current_day_count`, `previous_day_count` (with first day value as 0)

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| customer | current_date | current_day_count | previous_day_count |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Mark     | 2018_02_06   |                15 |                  0 |
|          | 2018_02_09   |                42 |                 33 |
|          | 2018_02_12   |                33 |                 82 |
|          | 2018_02_21   |                82 |                 72 |
|          | 2018_02_27   |                72 |                  0 |
| Bob      | 2018_02_02   |                76 |                  0 |
|          | 2018_02_23   |                11 |                 59 |
|          | 2018_03_04   |                59 |                 68 |
|          | 2018_03_13   |                68 |                  0 |
| Shawn    | 2018_02_11   |                71 |                  0 |
|          | 2018_02_15   |                39 |                 65 |
|          | 2018_02_18   |                65 |                 38 |
|          | 2018_02_24   |                38 |                  0 |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Mark','Mark','Mark','Mark','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob'], 'current_day_count': [18,28,29,10,19,92,7,43]})

df['previous_day_count'] = df.groupby('name')['current_day_count'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df.groupby('name',as_index=False).head(1).index,'previous_day_count'] = np.nan
df['previous_day_count'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```